# How to show all the terms in a sequence are greater than a number?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Prove that if $\left\{ x_n \right\}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ converges to $3$, then there exists an $N$ such that $x_n > 2$ for all $n \geq N$.

I was thinking there are two cases; one where the sequence converges "from above," meaning the sequence starts with some number greater than $3$ and eventually converges "down" to $3$, and the other case where the sequence starts at some number $< 3$ and converges "up" towards $3$. Is this problem the same as showing that $\left\{ x_n \right\}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ also converges to $2$?

Comment: Isn't this a necessary condition from the definition of limit?

Comment: Your cases are not the only possibilities..

Comment: Use the definition of sequence convergence.. That is given $\epsilon >0,$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $ |x_n-3|< \epsilon $ for all $ n> N$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\{x_n\}$ converges to $3$, given $\epsilon >0,$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $ |x_n-3|< \epsilon $ for all $ n> N$.

So take $\epsilon=1$. Then there exists $N \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $ |x_n-3|< 1 $ for all $ n> N$.

$\Rightarrow -1<x_n-3 < 1$ for all $ n> N$.

$\Rightarrow 2 < x_n$ for all $ n> N$.